# Transferred IRA account - incurred a fee and got reimbursed

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, retirement

I transferred some IRA (both Traditional and Roth) accounts and incurred a total of $300 in fees by my originating firm that was subtracted before those transfers took place.

The target firm reimbursed me for those fees but did it by adding $300 to a brokerage (non-IRA) account.

Are there any tax implications in this?

Comment: What's the originating firm's name?